# Chrome devtools crashes on breakpoint in EventListener

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, debugging, crash

I have a very weird issue in Chrome, when I put a debugger statement in a prototype.js eventlistener, it crashes. Is this a bug in Chrome?

```js
var input = document.getElementById("input");

input.observe("change", function (event) {
    // This line crashes Chrome!
    debugger;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/prototype/1.7.2/prototype.min.js"></script>
<input id="input" type="text" value="" />
```

[image]

I'm using Chrome 42.0.2311.50 beta-m (64-bit)

Comment: It also crashes if you put a regular breakpoint there.

Comment: ...And it also crashes in a normal eventListener.

Comment: Submitted ticket: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=469095